# jQuery modal window with animation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Is there a way to show an animation when showing the jQuery modal window? When a user clicks on a button, I would like the modal window to do slowly emerge out of the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated) is a working example of adding some animation capabilities to the jquery ui dialog.

This isn't exactly a flyout, but if you started this with a an absolute position and smaller size at the window `offset` of the button that was clicked and then animated it to it's initial state, you could recreate the effect that you want.

Otherwise I might suggest using a plugin that does this natively.

http://fancybox.net/ does this for instance.

Comment: Where can i see the syntax for the jquery ui dialog on googlecode?